# simple assembly syscall not working

Tags: assembly, x86, freebsd

I'm following [those video tutorials](http://securitytube.net/Assembly-Primer-for-Hackers-%28Part-1%29-System-Organization-video.aspx) on the assembly language.
I'm basically trying to work out the "hello world" asm example.
Here is what I've got:

```
.data
str:
        .ascii "Hello World"

.text
.globl _start

_start:
        movl    $4, %eax
        movl    $1, %ebx
        movl    $str, %ecx
        movl    $11, %edx
        int     $0x80

        movl    $1, %eax
        movl    $0, %ebx
        int     $0x80
```

This compiles just fine but when I run it, no text is printed to the terminal. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Whatever value I mov into the ecx register makes no difference, nothing happens.

Also, other question, how does the syscall work when it call the int 0x80 instruction ?
Some data has been moved to the registers but when we get to the syscall, it doesn't "use" any of those values. Does it go and get what has been moved to those registers on it's own ?

Some system info that might be helpful:

```
dominic-@-freebsd-9 ~/dev/asm/tutorial > uname -a
FreeBSD freebsd-9 5.5-RELEASE FreeBSD 5.5-RELEASE #0: Tue May 23 14:58:27 UTC 2006     root@perseus.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  i386
```

Comment: My personal opinion is that starting assembly by learning system calls, "hello world", calling conventions and other OS dependent features is a bad idea. I usually recommend learning the use of a debugger and writing little self-contained asm programs that you can single step, such as summing up a small array. Once you are happy with the basic instructions and get the hang of assembly, you can easily learn the various other things, whereby knowing system calls may not even be useful. But that's just my crazy view :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need Linux emulation for this to work. Take a look into [Developer's Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helped me figure this out. FreeBSD requires that params to be passed on the stack, I was using the wrong calling convention.

Answer (score 1):

> FreeBSD has the more 'usual' calling
>   convention, where the syscall number
>   is in eax, and the parameters are on
>   the stack

- http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/hello.html

check out the freebsd section of this hello world in assembly totorial

I go between ubuntu and netbsd and that helped me write assembly for both

*bsd uses a stack to store the arguments of the file des and the length of bytes to write, in linux it's just kept in the registers eax and ebx which is linux style, as you have in your example.

in linux:
    _start:;tell linker entry point
        mov edx,len ;message length
        mov ecx,msg ;message to write
        mov ebx,1 ;file descriptor (stdout)
        mov eax,4 ;system call number (sys_write)
        int 0x80  ;call kernel

in freebsd:

```
_syscall:
    int0x80;system call
    ret 

_start:;tell linker entry point

    pushd word len;message length
    pushd word msg;message to write
    pushd word 1;file descriptor (stdout)
    move ax,0x4;system call number (sys_write)
    call _syscall;call kernel
```

use the stack version for syscalls on *bsd

Comment: Yeah as I said I worked it out by reading the FreeBSD docs, but thanks for the further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have %ebx set to 0 (stdout). Your current value (1) means stdin.

Comment: that is the exit syscall status param, not the fd I'm writing to.

Comment: stdin is 0 and stdout is 1 stderr is 2

Comment: @Fire Crow: on linux stdin is 1 and stdout is 0. I didn't see that he's running freeBsd.

Comment: ummmm... no stdin is still 0 on linux

Comment: @Fire Crow: I did a sort of hello world using 0 as stdout and 1 as stdin. it works.

Comment: $ man 3 stdin - on ubuntu "...the  integer  file  descriptors  associated with the streams stdin, stdout, and stderr are 0, 1, and 2, respectively...", it's ok blackbear we all make mistakes once in a while.

Comment: @Fire Crow: Ok, last question then. Why my asm program, which uses 0 as stdout and 1 as stdin, works correctly?

Comment: it doesn't your probably mistaking which register is used for something like a return code or something like a file descriptor, at least that's my best guess without seeing the code, or maybe working just means that your writing into your own stdin.

Comment: @Fire Crow: Ach, those computers! ;)

Comment: @BlackBear: yeah I know, so easy to get confused, switching TIOCGWINSZ for TIOCSWINSZ was killing my terminal yesterday, just missed that the *G* in the first is different from the *S* in the second. those computers! :)